# How do I load the initial UIViewController in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS development, and I know I'm missing something simple but I'm not sure what it is... I have a simple "Hello World" app, and I'm trying to get my initial view controller to load.

Steps taken:

1. I created an empty project
2. I added a custom view controller class that extends UIViewController:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()
@end

@implementation WebViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

3. I added a Storyboard using Apple's wizard.
4. I added a view controller to that storyboard.
5. I set my custom controller as the "Custom Class" of that view controller.
6. I checked the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox.
   [image: storyboard]

But when I run the app, my controller does not load (viewDidLoad is never called).  What am I missing?

Sorry about the noob question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Enlarge the image.  Where it says "Main Interface", select the storyboard you want to launch with from this menu.  You may to shake Xcode a bit before your storyboard shows up in the list.  If it's now showing up, try things like saving the storyboard file as well as cleaning/building your project.  Image is borrowed from [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/).

---

In your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {` method in your app delegate `.m` file:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
    @"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard 
    instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is an *alternative* to "Main Interface" setting, correct? (not *in addition* to that setting)

Comment: That is correct Troy.  If you start a new project with an option like single-view application, the "Main Interface" setting will be set by default to the automatically generated storyboard and you won't have to touch your app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

in storyboard you dont need `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;` As your storyboard the WebViewController is inital view controller so you dont need any thing in appDelegate. The WebViewController will auto call